# Menu size and position

Tags: html, css, menu

Everytime when I open html, menu position and size is different. Could you help me to fix it? It is supposed to be at the center. Thanks for any help.

```
div.menu { 
    list-style:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;} 
div.menu ul{ 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size:14px; 
    margin:20px; 
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;} 
div.menu li{ 
    display:inline; } 
div.menu li a{ 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:5px 0; 
    width:100px; 
    background:#FBB117; 
    color:#4C4646; 
    float:left; 
    text-align:center; 
    border-left:1px solid #fff; }  
div.menu li a:hover{ 
    background:#a2b3a1; 
    color:#000 }
```

Comment: It helps if you post some trimmed down html showing the problem, and perhaps trim down the css to the problematic bits (e.g. background colors and the like are probably not important?). In addition, it helps if you tell us what you tried and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Why did you make `div.menu ul` `display:inline-block`? Unless there is something that we haven't seen in the HTML, the ul should just be its default display.

Comment: I'm guessing he made `div.menu ul` `display: inline-block;` because he wants to center it using `text-align: center;` But there is no way to solve his problem without seeing the html. I'm guessing it's a missing doctype.

Comment: Actually, using display: inline-block to center stuff is a pretty neat solution. It doesn't work in IE7 and below though.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I think it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can centre an element by using the margin tag. For this work to though, you'll have to declare the width of `div.menu ul` otherwise it'll inherit the width of it's parent element, `div.menu`. Therefore:

```
div.menu ul{ 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    font-size:14px; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100px; <!-- SPECIFY WIDTH -->
}
```

Comment: I added padding:0; display:inline-block; too and I think it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good stuff, please can you mark this answer as 'correct' by ticking the green tick, would appreciate it :)

Comment: I cannot see any green tick. where is it exactly?

Comment: Beneath the the large up and down number area next to my answer :)